# Conditional operation on Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataset where one of the column holds total sq.ft value.

```
1151
1025
2100 - 2850
1075
1760
```

I would like to split the 2100 - 2850 if the dataframe contains '-' and take its average(mean) as the new value. I am trying achieve this using apply method but running into error when statement containing contains is executing. Please suggest how to handle this situation.

```
def convert_totSqft(s):
    if s.str.contains('-', regex=False) == True
        << some statements>>
    else:
        << some statements>>

X['new_col'] = X['total_sqft'].apply(convert_totSqft)
```

Error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-6-af39b196879b>", line 2, in convert_totSqft
    if s.str.contains('-', regex=False) == True:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.col.str.split('-',expand=True).apply(pd.to_numeric).mean(1)
Out[630]: 
0    1151.0
1    1025.0
2    2475.0
3    1075.0
4    1760.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Just one more question. The same column 'total_sqft' also contains values like 120Sqft, 1600Sq ft etc. So when I tried to apply it gives me error for these values. So I am trying to achieve this - a) if '-' appearing then split and take the average 2) drop which are not int or float 3) use rest of the values as is.

I tried to use if condition as using contains as mentioned in the original question. Can you please suggest how to handle this situation.

Comment: @ChetanAmbi using `df['total_sqft']=df['total_sqft'].str.extract('(\d+)',expand=True)` before apply my solution

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I missed to add few more points. total_sqft contains values in pure sq. ft in ints or floats and then also contains values like 120Sq ft. 150 Sq meters, 190Yards` i.e. its mentioned in different metrics. So using 'contains' in if condition I was trying convert other metrics to Sq ft but I am not able to get through this problem. Your both the answer does work for specific scenario like if this column contains only Sq ft values. Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can `split` by `-` anyway and just `transform` using `np.mean`, once the mean of a single number is just the number itself

```
df.col.str.split('-').transform(lambda s: np.mean([int(x.strip()) for x in s]))

0    1151.0
1    1025.0
2    2475.0
3    1075.0
4    1760.0
```

Alternatively, you can `sum` and divide by `len` (same thing)

```
df.col.str.split('-').transform(lambda s: sum([int(x.strip()) for x in s])/len(s))
```

If want results back necessarily as `int`, just wrap it with `int()`

```
df.col.str.split('-').transform(lambda s: int(np.mean([int(x.strip()) for x in s])))

0    1151
1    1025
2    2475
3    1075
4    1760
```

Comment: thanks for the response Rafael. I tried you code but getting error message. 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: @user180165 do not use apply. Use `df.col` directly, where `col` is your column name

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions I am still getting same error. 

1) `X['total_sqft'].str.split('-').transform(lambda s: np.mean([int(x.strip()) for x in s]))

2) X['total_sqft'].str.split('-').transform(lambda s: sum([int(x.strip()) for x in s])/len(s))`

Comment: @ChetanAmbi thats very weird. You error is basically saying that `X['total_sqft']` is a list, which clearly is not. Either that or this error Is raised in some other part of the code

Comment: I ran your solution again today and it works fine ! The reason I was running into errors is because `'total_sqft'` column has other values like `120Sq ft, 150 Sq meters, 190Yards`. Now, I want to do this - a) if there is 150 Sq mts then i want to covert it to sq ft and same for sq yards etc. b) if there is range like 2100 - 2850 then will take mean values 3) in all other cases will consider whatever value present in the column.  Is it possible to achieve all these steps? Kindly suggest